# Pass arguments in ElapsedEventHandler C++/CLI

Tags: timer, arguments, c++-cli, system

How do I pass arguments to my function with ElapsedEventHandler?

`NewTimer->Elapsed+=gcnew ElapsedEventHandler(&TimerEvent(String1,String2));` ???

I get this error:

`'System::Timers::ElapsedEventHandler' : a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ElapsedEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.elapsedeventhandler.aspx) defines a delegate that takes two parameters:

- The object that raised the event (the timer object).
- [`ElapsedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.elapsedeventargs.aspx), which contains the time that the timer was triggered.

If you need other information in your event handler, store them in fields on your class, and reference them that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, perhaps you could link/show me an example of doing this correctly? I tried searching my self, no luck.

Comment: `timer->Elapsed += gcnew ElapsedEventHandler(this, &ThisClass::TimerEvent);`. Leave out the 'this' parameter if it's a static method.